# Can Golang mobile be used with React-Native?

Tags: android, ios, go, react-native

I'm considering writing a mobile app using both Go's mobile lib https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/mobile (I know it's experimental, so this is more of a wait and see situation) for a data layer and a polyfill for the android view and use React-native http://facebook.github.io/react-native/ for the iOS view and hopefully the android view once that is supported (if it is/will be supported).

How much conflict would I have in doing this, if any? I assume I could pass data between the two libraries from each respective native (as in obj-c and java, I know this all compiles to a native app) languages.

**To Clarify**

Go's mobile lib and react-native would both be compiled into the mobile client.  The go lib makes requests to a server and is not the server.

**UPDATE**

So React Native came out for Android, so now I'm just wondering how go mobile and react native and communicate between each other within the same app executable.

Comment: my pratice: https://github.com/jan4984/UnsEduOralevaldemo. to do a http server with go(easy), to do a pure web application(like in browser-easy). pass data between view and background server with standard http ajax.

Comment: As long as you get Gomob and ReactNative to work separately, you wouldn't have a problem attaching them if you speak http between them.

Comment: So it seems there's a misunderstanding.  Go's mobile lib *is not* server side it would compile with react-native on the mobile client side. As in the go mobile side makes requests to the server then I want to send that response data to react-native to template into a view.  With that in mind, why would I want to talk http between the two?

Comment: I think they are assuming that the go lib is on the phone, and it exposes a http interface to the react native lib ? Just my reading.

Comment: I'm not too sure, but that's even more odd of a solution in that case haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. You may include the generated code in your react native project and write some "glue code" (an objective-c and java class) that requires your go library and uses the [Native Module extension](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html) by React Native to get access to the provided functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that React Native can be used to make mobile apps with any language that can run on the web.  Currently I am learning how to make  React app with a Golang backend. Later I will build this in React Native and start building other apps with Golang to see how far this goes. There is a course on udemy that teaches golang and react and it isn't that long.